# Best way to disable entire form on PHP condition?

Tags: jquery, html, webforms

I have a site (like many). I want to *show* but disable a particular form based on whether they are logged in or not. The way I show if the user is logged in is via a cookie set by PHP. What I'm wondering is the best way to disable all the elements in the form when the user is not logged in.

The solution I have at the moment is to get PHP to `echo` some JavaScript (jQuery to be precise) to the page:

```
$("#form_name").children("input, textarea").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Is this the right way to go, or is there a better way to be doing things?

Comment: Looks good to me. If you have additional elements (selects/etc)  you can just add them into your children function.  Though there may be a way of disabling the entire form in jquery that I may not know about

Comment: You should use .find(..) instead of .children(..) as the latter only searches immediate children

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the cookie set when PHP generates your page, just set the disabled attribute on the HTML element without Javascript. Then, if you have an ajaxy login form, you can parse the login response and enable the form based on that. If the login isn't ajaxy, PHP should set the cookie for you and build the page appropriately.

Comment: Perfect - thanks! I wanted to be sure I was doing it right and not missing something out that would work better. +1 for you my good man; thanks for the quick answer :-)

Comment: Thanks! To be clear, your original approach relies on JS, but I would put it in the HTML inline. `<input type='text'<?php if(condition){ ?> disabled<?php } ?>> It'll be a little more verbose, but it also will still work if js is disabled.

Comment: Hmm good point with the lack of JavaScript. The site I'm developing is primarily for web-devs, and in 2009 only something like 2.4% of users had JS disabled, which is acceptable. (http://smorgasbork.com/component/content/article/84-a-study-of-internet-users-cookie-and-javascript-settings)

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery you could find all input, select, and textarea elements that are not currently disabled and disable them, using the [:enabled selector](http://api.jquery.com/enabled-selector/)

```
$("#form_id").find("input:enabled, select:enabled, textarea:enabled").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Comment: Ah I missed the `select` tag - thanks! Also, as all the elements in the page are either disabled or enabled, the `:enabled` line doesn't really matter/apply, but thanks for the heads up :-)

Answer (score 1):

If the user does not have javascript enabled then of course this answer is: this is not a good idea.

Second just using disabled inputs is also a bad idea, a malicious user can tweak your page and easily reenable.

That said all is fine as long as you ensure that the fields that you want disabled are not accepted on the server side post.

Comment: Good point with the JS being disabled... as for tweaking the page, the code executed on submission of the form will check to see if the user is logged in anyway, so that should be secure enough I think.